# What is the use of & in scss of some page

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I have not understood the use of '&' in scss of some page and also the scss I have not understood.

**some-page.scss**

```
some-page-selector {

    & ion-item {
        &.item {
            //some properties

            &[margin-bottom] {
                //some property
            }

            & ion-avatar {
                //some property
            }

            & ion-avatar ion-img,
            & ion-avatar img {
               //some property
            }

}
```

Comment: Refer this link you will be clarified https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: thanks... you can paste the link in my answers I will accept it as well.:)

Comment: Refer this link you will be clarified https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: Ok sure. I will post the link in answer

Answer (score 1):

In Sass, the `&` (ampersand) references the parent (or chain of parents) of a block of code.

Given this SCSS (similar to what you posted) ...

```scss
page {
  & ion-item {               // => page ion-item
    &.item {                 // => page ion-item.item
      color: red;

      &[margin-bottom] {     // => page ion-item.item[margin-bottom]
        margin-bottom: 1em;
      }

      & ion-avatar {         // => page ion-item.item ion-avatar
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... you will get this compiled CSS:

```css
page ion-item.item {
  color: red;
}
page ion-item.item[margin-bottom] {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
page ion-item.item ion-avatar {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```